# MPMoviePlayerController not released

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am running an intro movie in a MPMoviePlayerController and i've got a problem with the allocated memory not being released.
When the movie finishes, Instruments shows the memory being released.
However when i skip the movie by tapping on it the memory is not released.
Here are the important parts of my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)theApplication {
self.application = theApplication; 
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mymovie.mov" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
[window addSubview:moviePlayer.view];


moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.view.frame = window.frame;


UIView *introFrontView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
introFrontView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
introFrontView.opaque = NO;
introTabRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
             action:@selector(introTabFrom:)];
[introFrontView addGestureRecognizer:introTabRecognizer];
[moviePlayer.view addSubview:introFrontView];
[introFrontView release];
[introTabRecognizer release];
self.moviePlayerController = moviePlayer;
[moviePlayer release];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(introFinished:) 
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
          object:self.moviePlayerController];
[self.moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)introTabFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
          object:self.moviePlayerController];
}

- (void) introFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
          object:self.moviePlayerController];
[self.moviePlayerController pause];
[self.moviePlayerController stop];
[self.moviePlayerController release];
...
}
```

Is there anything i forgot?
 To my understanding i'm posting the correct notification...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to register for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, and look at the playbackState that is passed in.