# MPMoviePlayerController memory not released when video not completely played

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

In ipad when video played using MPMoviePlayerController large memory allocated . That memory is released if the video played to the end ,but when navigate away from the view without the end of the video the memory allocated is not completely released.I want release all the memory associated with the player when the user want to navigate away from the view (even if the video not played to the end) .Please guide me on how this can be achieved.

-(void)playMovieAtURL:(NSURL*)theURL

{

```
   player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];

   CGRect frame= CGRectMake(0.0,60.0,768.0,650.0);

   [[player view] setFrame:frame]; 

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];   

   [self.view addSubview:player.view];

   [player play];
```

}

-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification{

```
[player.view removeFromSuperview];
[player stop];
player.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player] ;
[player release];
player=nil;
```

}

given below is the function for getting diffrent slides like viedo or picture

-(void)getSlide

{
    if(player !=nil)
    {

```
    if(urlp !=nil)
    {
        [urlp release];
        urlp=nil;

    }
    [player pause];
    [player stop];

}
```

.....
....
....

```
 if(type =video)

   {
          urlp =[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:toPlay];
          [self playMovieAtURL:urlp];
          [urlp release];


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think `[player release];` and `player = nil;` should do it. Make sure you do this before navigating to another view.

Comment: -(void)getSlide  is the method invoked when navigate to another slide  ,so in that function if(player !=nil)  [player stop];
 is given , i hope that will invoke -(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification ,there it's releasing player

Comment: Can you check if the notification method is called on stop coz I am not sure it does. Pls correct me if i am wrong. Check using a breakpoint or print something in console

Comment: i given a message for printing and its printed in console

Comment: If stop calls the method it should release but there is another stop inside the method right? So wont it be called again.

Comment: you are right but the method only invoked once , so i am not sure whether stop calls the notification method or its called when navigating to another view ,anyways notification method is invoked and the message printed in console once when i click the next button .

Comment: You can then try releasing the player just after the stop statement in the getSlide method. It may help.

Comment: yes i tried releasing player in getslide but the memory allocated is still not released completely when i check the application using instruments :(

Comment: Pls try removing the notification also when you navigate. I am not sure if it may help you.

Comment: Did u run the static analyzer to see if there are any leaks?

Comment: Before taking the video the memory allocation for the app is around 2-3 mb after taking the video its hiked to around 90mb if the video played till the end and navigate to another view memory reduced to around 5 mb , but if i navigate before the end of video ,around 20 mb remains allocated

Comment: it will depend on the number of video's available to play . But currently i am testing it using a single video so its only called once

Comment: pls make sure the player is not allocated again. This will not solve the problem but make sure you do this.

Comment: yes its not allocated again , but i didn't understand why that memory is not released when navigate to another view without completing the video and its released if navigate after the end of the video

Comment: just release and make it nil before every allocation. Coz when when u release the retain count is reduced only by 1 that is only one instance is released.

Comment: i checked the retaincount of player , after releasing its 0

Comment: Just see if there are any other objects thats causing the leak

Comment: i didn't find any leaks ,static analyzer also not showing any leaks , and memory correctly released if the video played to the end thats y i am in confusion

Comment: Are you transferring the video to a file? I think the data is stored there and released only when movie is finished

Comment: i found someone else also asked about the same problem in stackoverflow                                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164308/mpmovieplayercontroller-not-released                                                         unfortunately no answer :(

Comment: Memory remain unallocated reduced when the resolution of the video changed to 640*480 ,(early it was 1024*707)

Comment: what will be the best resolution of video to be set , player frame is set using CGRectMake(0.0,60.0,768.0,650.0) .Also option available for full screen mode